# See console logs in the firebase server functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I see tons of spam log messages in the firebase functions log console, but I cannot see the ones I log, so the ones I expect to see.

My code:

```
const createNotification = ((notification) => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('notifications')
    .add(notification)
    .then(doc => console.log('notification added', doc)); //THIS IS THE LOG I EXPECT TO SEE
});

exports.userJoined = functions.auth.user()
  .onCreate(user => {
    
    return admin.firestore().collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {

        const newUser = doc.data();
        const notification = {
          content: 'Joined the party',
          user: `${newUser.firstName} ${newUser.lastName}`,
          time: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        };

        return createNotification(notification);

      });
});
```

In the promise I also tried: `.then(() => console.log('notification added', notification));`
The notification is created in the database but no log in the conosole.
This time I am lucky and the code works, but in the case the code is not working I would like to be able to log stuff out.

In my reduxfirebase config I got enableLogging to true, in case that could make any difference.

```
export const reduxFirebase = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
  enableLogging: true
}
```

Any tip to debug server function execution in firebase also will be much appreciatted. Thanks

EDIT: Image of the obtained firebase log:
[image]

Expected log:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs you *do* see in the functions console? Nothing is obviously wrong with your code, so seeing what output you're getting will help.

Comment: updated image in the question. Arrows suggesting a dropdown do not show any content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `console.log` with `functions.logger.info` -- I think what's happening is your log is getting exploded onto multiple lines in a way that reads confusingly.

Comment: That just made it. Thank you very much!